# How can I select an image source that's the same size as the original image after adding sources?

Tags: javascript, image, figure, srcset

I have a set of code I am working on.  In my HTML, I identify an Img with an ID, then Javascript takes that ID, finds the actual href and setups a lot of srcset and other attributes:

```html
<img id="drinks" height="130" alt="Serve myself $150 cognac?  Don't mind if I do'" />
```

and after magicery, it comes out like this:

```html
<figure><img id="drinks" height="130" alt="Serve myself $150 cognac?  Don't mind if I do" srcset="images/jalhanedafirst2019/drinksfx.jpg 501w, images/jalhanedafirst2019/drinks1x.jpg 1000w, 
images/jalhanedafirst2019/drinks2x.jpg 2000w, images/jalhanedafirst2019/drinks3x.jpg 4000w, 
images/jalhanedafirst2019/drinks4x.jpg 5000w" src="images/jalhanedafirst2019/drinks1x.jpg" border="2" sizes="(min-width: 501px) 200px">
  <figcaption>Serve myself $150 cognac? Don't mind if I do
  </figcaption>
</figure>
```

My problem is I want the  to end up same size as the image AFTER it's done figuring out the size of the page, the widths of the images, and picking the correct one from the srcset.

FYI, I am NOT using jquery.

I have tried MutationObserver, and running after document.onload, but those do not catch it at the right time (many image widths are 0 at the run time or Mutation doesn't even catch the change in size on attributes).

And, the times it actually DOES catch it by luck, the Figure size doesn't get changed to match the child image.

```js
var els = document.querySelectorAll("figure");

for (var x = 0; x < els.length; x++) {
  var child = els[x].children;
  var i1 = 0;
  var i2 = 0;
  for (var y = 0; y < child.length; y++) {
    if (child[y] instanceof HTMLImageElement) {
      i1 = y;
    } else
      i2 = y;
  }
  console.debug(i2 + ":" + i1);
  console.debug(child[i1].id);
  console.debug(child[i1].width);
  child[i2].width = child[i1].width;
  console.debug(child[i2].width);
  els[x].width = child[i1].width;
}
```

Any ideas?